# Custom Assets In Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Working with custom fonts or assets in `Google Cloud function`

```
const fonts = {
  Courier: {
    normal: 'fonst/Courier.ttf',
    bold: 'fonts/Courier-Bold.ttf',
    italics: 'fonts/Courier-Oblique.ttf',
    bolditalics: 'fonts/Courier-BoldOblique.ttf'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a project structure like this, will not work

```
/functions
    /lib <----- generated by tsc build 
      /fonts <------- manually copied fonts
        myfont.ttf
    /src 
      index.ts
      /fonts. <------- you custom fonts
         myfont.ttf
```

`index.ts`

```
const fonts = 'fonts/myfont.ttf';
```

Solution

```
/functions
    /fonts <------- Creat fonts folder in root
      myfont.ttf
    /lib <----- generated by tsc build 
    /src 
      index.ts
```

`index.ts` will remain the same

```
const fonts = 'fonts/myfont.ttf';
```